# Functional data structure

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, linear-algebra

I'm currently trying to make a non-trivial calculator like Maple, wolfram alpha and those. Just for fun. But I have made the constraint that it has to be in a pure strict functional language. That means no lazy evaluation and mutable structures like arrays.

The question is simply what would be an efficient data structure to make vectors and matrices? The "easy" go to answer would of course be lists, but I find them highly inefficient when it comes to products of matrices. To formalize even more, the vectors and matrices should be of arbitrary size.

Comment: What particular language are you asking about? Often they come with an efficient implementation of vectors.

Comment: SML's standard basis library has a structure called `Vector`, which is an immutable linear data structure with `O(1)` access (see http://sml-family.org/Basis/vector.html ). Without built-in language support you will be hard-pressed to do non-trivial linear algebra (since immutability is already a major handicap when it comes to many algorithms).

Comment: *"But I have made the constraint that it has to be in a pure strict functional language. That means no lazy evaluation ..."* – why no lazy evaluation?

Comment: Trees and lists can aid you in making structures that makes low amortized big O without lazy evaluation. Basically you do it eagerly at need.

Comment: Bergi the language is not importened. It is only syntaks in difference.

Comment: John I know but thanks, they use an underlying array to represent it, so that would not do it.

Comment: Sylwester thanks it help alot

Answer (score 0):

You can leave it abstract by representing vectors and matrices as a product type (e.g. record or tuple) of dimensions and a function from index or row and column to element value. Note that you could also accumulate symbolic vector-matrix expressions and, therefore, simplify them before evaluation in order to eliminate as many temporaries as possible.

If your vectors and matrices are sparse then you might want to use a dictionary for the concrete representation. If they are dense then you might want to use an immutable array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon

I found a better structure, or semi the same.

I use a binary three as structure, where every left child is the subtree with root that is the node with key value that is the next entry of the column of the matrix and the right child is the next node in the row. so it would look like

```
1 -- 2 -- 3
|    |    |
4 -- 5 -- 6
|    |    |
7 -- 8 -- 9
```

Where | is the left node and -- is the right node of the tree, it is even possible to not represent the same node twice.

So if we have the matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

where node(Left, 1, Right) would be the root of the tree, and Left is the submatrix

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

where Node(_, 4, _) is the root of this matrix and Right is the submatrix

```
2 3
5 6
8 9
```

with root Node(_, 2, _).

This is at worst as good as arrays if we analyse the worst case runtime.
in some cases it is faster, if we for example wish to get the submatrix

```
5 6
8 9
```

We simple go one left and then right from the root and we have the whole tree.
We get the same properties we have with single linked list, as we can create a new matrix or vector(1 x m or m x 1 matrix) of an existing one simply adding the new nodes and det the children to the right node in the old matrix, and still have the old matrix.